# Make restore purchases option iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My problem with restore my purchases.

I use this tutorial for integrate IAP to my app [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

But after I have upload my binary on app store, Apple reject my app because it not use restore option.

Now I try to integrate this method to app

```
- (void)restorePurchases {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

but I think that still need to do something, because it still not work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement these delegate methods for completion of restoring

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```